# how to hide some dom element in html code of webpage in android?

Tags: javascript

i have spent much time looking for the solution of this problem but i coundn't find it at all. i tried the following code but it doesn't seem to work so plese help me out......

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
            WebView webView;
            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
                webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
                    @Override
                    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                        webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() {document.getElementById('header')[0].style.display='none';})()");
                    }
                });
                webView.loadUrl(url);
            }
        }
```

Comment: use `document.getElementById('header').style.display='none';` instead of `document.getElementById('header')[0].style.display='none';`

Comment: Thank you Rakib ....it really worked for me...but the div(header)  is hided after the page is fully loaded can you tell me how to directly set display = "none" and then showing in webview ?? any idea ??

Comment: Can you please mark my answer as accepted one so other can get help in future. Actually i am not Android expert :) so i am not sure how to do that. May be you can post another question about this new issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `ID`(header) should be unique within a page. However, if more than one element with the specified ID exists, the getElementById() method returns the first element.

So use

```
document.getElementById('header').style.display='none';
```

instead of

```
document.getElementById('header')[0].style.display='none';
```

Comment: Hello again Rakib,...would you please check out the code for hiding element with class name .....it is not working ....                                            public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl("javascript:(function() {document.getElementsByClassName('logo').style.display='none';})()");
            }

Comment: `var x = document.getElementsByClassName("logo");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
}`